# How do I pass down my search results to other components as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Looking to solve how to pass my search results to other components so when users use the search bar, the searched results gets displayed instead of that components rendered data.. in this case it would homeScreen. using react router v5 and i tried passing it through the router but many attempts didn't work, should i create a seperate search router too?

App.js:

```
<Container>
  <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
  <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} exact />
  <Route path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} exact />
  <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} exact />
  <Route path="/cart/:id?" component={CartScreen} exact />
</Container>
```

header.js:

```
function Header() {
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;
  // const [items, setItems] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const debounce = useDebounce(searchResults, 500);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/search/?search=${searchResults}`).then((response) => {
      setSearchResults(response.data[0]);
      console.log(response.data[0]);
    });
  }, [debounce]);

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearchResults(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" className="navCustom">
        <Container>
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand>eCommerce</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Form className="d-flex">
            <Form.Control
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              className="me-2"
              aria-label="Search"
              onChange={handleSearch}
            />
            <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
          </Form>
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
function HomeScreen({ searchResults }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { error, loading, products } = productList;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      {searchResults.length > 0 ? (
        <Row>
          {searchResults.map((product) => (
            <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
              <Product product={product} />
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      ) : (
        // Fall back to rendering regular products
        <Row>
          {products &&
            products.map((product) => (
              <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                <Product product={product} />
              </Col>
            ))}
        </Row>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use case of [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Within the Context, you can use useState to set the results. The Context can be provided to other components within your app.